# networking - How do I find out why my OpenVPN server is overwriting the source address?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

**Situation**:
I have a server and a client connected to an OpenVPN network. Both are assigned virtual IP addresses - `10.10.1.6` for the server and `10.10.1.14` for the client. Server starts listening on port `8090`. Client connects the server and binds on port `4444`. From a servers point of view I would expect source IP and source port to be `10.10.1.14:4444`, however it is `10.10.1.1:4444`.

**Bigger picture**:
There is an IOT device (RPi3) and a server connected to a VPN. Server needs to be able to address the IOT devices (that's a given), therefore IOT devices periodically "ping" the server so that it can keep track of their addresses (something similar to lwm2m registration mechanism).

**Additional info**:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/ $ ip addr
...
4: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 10.10.1.14 peer 10.10.1.13/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ... /64 scope link flags 800 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
>>> ip addr # server
...
6: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 10.10.1.6 peer 10.10.1.5/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ... /64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Testing the source address

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/ $ echo "hello" | ncat -p 4444 10.10.1.6 8090
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
>>> ncat -vvv -l -p 8090    # server
Ncat: Version 7.70 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Listening on :::8090
Ncat: Listening on 0.0.0.0:8090
...
Ncat: Connection from 10.10.1.1.
...
Ncat: Connection from 10.10.1.1:4444.
...
hello
...
```

I Have the same OpenVPN configuration as in https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-openvpn-server-and-client-with-easy-rsa-3-on-centos-7/ Step 4 - Configure OpenVPN

That being said, How do I "force" OpenVPN to pass me the "real" virtual source addresses? I am a beginner, so bear with me please.

**Edit**:
I tried the `ncat` test with both, client and listener running on the same machine, thus having the same virtual IP address and everything worked fine.

Comment: You're assuming this is default mode of operation -- but it is not. The real question should be "How do I find out why my OpenVPN server is overwriting the source address?"

Comment: It turned out that this indeed is default mode of operation

Answer (score 0):

The `10.10.1.1` address is a GW routing the traffic between `10.10.1.6` and `10.10.1.14`. OpenVPN clients can not see each other by default.

Adding `client-to-client` to `/etc/openvpn/server.conf` solved the problem.

See [archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/OpenVPN#Connect_clients_and_client_LANs) and [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/736274/openvpn-client-to-client).
Another solution is the "bridging" option described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/537668/why-cant-my-openvpn-client-access-machines-on-same-lan-as-openvpn-server).