# OpenVPN: cannot access remote client from devices on same local network as server

Tags: networking, openvpn

This is basically the problem [here](https://superuser.com/questions/537668/why-cant-my-openvpn-client-access-machines-on-same-lan-as-openvpn-server) but reversed. I have a remote OpenVPN client which connects to my server and registers itself with the address 10.1.0.29. This address is easily accessible from the server, whether through ping, ssh, or the apache web server. However, other machines on the local network of the server cannot access this 10.1.0.29 address in any way.

What could be the issue? The OpenVPN server does have ip_forwarding turned on, and the system works fine when the OpenVPN client is on the same LAN as the OpenVPN server. But as soon as the OpenVPN client is on a remote connection, it is not accessible to any machines on the ovpn server's LAN, only to the server itself.

See photo below: the packet is arriving to server and then even being retransmitted:
[image]

UPDATE: The client is receiving the packet too, it just refuses to acknowledge or do anything with it.

Routing options on client:
[image]

Comment: Did you configure your network to route the traffic to 10.1.0.29 over your server? If your router doesn't know about the fact that the device is only reachable over your openvpn server, it won't be able to deliver any packages to it.

Comment: Yes, my router routes all packets of the subnet 10.1.0.0/16 over to the OVPN server. On Wireshark I can see these packets arriving at my OVPN server, and then a packet from OVPN server to the OVPN client is sent.

Comment: I have added a wireshark photo for clarity, where 192.168.1.31 is my OVPN server

Comment: It is being [retransmitted](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/what-tcp-retransmissions-why-occur-ibraham-ajazz) because the destination did not acknowledge that it received the package. So it got lost somewhere on the way. Did you configure your server to route the packages correctly?

Comment: Do you have a firewall on the client and is the webserver configured to bind to the openvpn address range?

Comment: There is no firewall on client machine. I am not sure what you mean with the second part, however everything works fine if the client machine is on the same LAN with the server.  Re: retransmission - the packet reaches all the way to the client machine where it shows up normally, and then shows up as a retransmission

Comment: @mashuptwice could the problem on the client be the 192.168.1.134 is not being routed through 10.1.8.29 ? how would I fix this ?

Comment: https://openvpn.net/community-resources/setting-up-routing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the CLIENT machine, using `route -n`, make sure the local network addresses you want to connect to the client machine from, are being routed through your OpenVPN tun0 gateway. In my case, as the gateway was `10.1.8.29`, a simple `ip route add 192.168.1.134 via 10.1.8.29` sufficed to allow access.

More holistically, a `route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 10.1.8.29` in the client.conf file on the client machine does the trick for any device in my server's local network.